# why dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier cost most time?

Tags: ios, uitableview

there's a tableView in my app, but it scroll very slow. After profiling it with Instruments, it shows that `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` cost 93% time. I want to know why it cost so much time? I guess the reason is  I use a custom cell, which includes 10 views(label, imageView). but I don't know why a complicated custom cell can effect `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` method.

Comment: Do you have any images in the cells?

Comment: Do you implement `prepareForReuse`?

Comment: Yes, I have images @AbdullahShafique

Comment: @NOrder That may be the reasons why it is slow try taking out some or reducing the quality,

Comment: I didn't implement prepareForReuse, should I implement it?

Comment: hello Dear please try to use the lazyloading for the loading of images.If u search in net ASYnchronus imageview class and drag thos .h and .m class in it and make ur tableview faster

Comment: hi, please use lazyloading for images in tableview cell.